# Flatten a JSON document using jq by filtering an array by keys

Tags: json, select, jq, flatten

I have a JSON in the following format:

```
    {
  "subFields": [
    {
      "id": "question_1",
      "type": "radioGroup",
      "description": "Description1",
      "title": "title1",
      "subFields": [
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "Yes",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "No",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "uiComponent": "SmallContent",
          "componentProps": {
            "text": "* If the answer to the above question is “Yes”, please contact the Support immediately."
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "uiComponent": "Spacer"
    },
    {
      "id": "question_2",
      "type": "radioGroup",
      "description": "Description2",
      "title": "Title2",
      "subFields": [
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "Label - Value 1",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "Label - Value 2",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "Label - Value 3",
          "value": 3
        },
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "Other",
          "value": 13,
          "subFields": [
            {
              "id": "question_2a",
              "type": "string",
              "condition": {
                "type": "BinaryExpression",
                "operator": "==",
                "left": {
                  "type": "Identifier",
                  "name": "question_2"
                },
                "right": {
                  "type": "Literal",
                  "value": 13
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "question_2_b",
      "style": {
        "marginTop": "30px"
      },
      "type": "radioGroup",
      "description": "Description3",
      "title": "",
      "subFields": [
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "Label - Radio 1",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "Label - Radio 2",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "Label - Radio 3",
          "value": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "uiComponent": "Spacer"
    },
    {
      "id": "question_3",
      "type": "radioGroup",
      "description": "Description3",
      "title": "Title3",
      "subFields": [
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "Yes",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "type": "radio",
          "label": "No",
          "value": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "uiComponent": "Spacer"
    },
    {
      "condition": {
        "type": "BinaryExpression",
        "operator": "==",
        "left": {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "name": "signer_type"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "Literal",
          "value": "entity"
        }
      },
      "subFields": [
        {
          "uiComponent": "Spacer"
        },
        {
          "id": "question_4",
          "type": "radioGroup",
          "description": "Description_4",
          "title": "Title_4",
          "subFields": [
            {
              "type": "radio",
              "label": "Yes",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "type": "radio",
              "label": "No",
              "value": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "uiComponent": "Spacer"
        }
      ],
      "uiComponent": "Block"
    },
    {
      "uiComponent": "Spacer"
    }
  ],
  "uiComponent": "Container"
}
```

and I would like to generate the following output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "question_1",
        "title": "title1",
        "description": "Description1",
        "type": "radioGroup",
        "questions": "radio,Yes,1"
    },
    {
        "id": "question_1",
        "title": "title1",
        "description": "Description1",
        "type": "radioGroup",
        "questions": "radio,No,0"
    },
    {
        "id": "question_2",
        "title": "Title2",
        "description": "Description2",
        "type": "radioGroup",
        "questions": "radio,Label - Value 1,1"
    },
    {
        "id": "question_2",
        "title": "Title2",
        "description": "Description2",
        "type": "radioGroup",
        "questions": "radio,Label - Value 2,2"
    },
    {
        "id": "question_2",
        "title": "Title2",
        "description": "Description2",
        "type": "radioGroup",
        "questions": "radio,Label - Value 3,3"
    },
    {
        "id": "question_2_b",
        "title": "",
        "description": "Description3",
        "type": "radioGroup",
        "questions": "radio,Label - Value 1,1"
    },
    {
        "id": "question_2_b",
        "title": "",
        "description": "Description3",
        "type": "radioGroup",
        "questions": "radio,Label - Value 2,2"
    },
    {
        "id": "question_2_b",
        "title": "",
        "description": "Description3",
        "type": "radioGroup",
        "questions": "radio,Label - Value 3,3"
    },
    {
        "id": "question_3",
        "title": "Title3",
        "description": "Description3",
        "type": "radioGroup",
        "questions": "radio,Yes,1"
    },
    {
        "id": "question_3",
        "title": "Title3",
        "description": "Description3",
        "type": "radioGroup",
        "questions": "radio,No,0"
    }
]
```

or in alternative a reduced version:

```
[
  "question_1",
  "title1",
  "Description1",
  "radioGroup",
  "radio,Yes,1",
  "radio,No,0"
],
[
  "question_2",
  "title2",
  "Description2",
  "radioGroup",
  "radio,Label - Value 1,1",
  "radio,Label - Value 2,2",
  "radio,Label - Value 3,3",
],
[
  "question_2_b",
  "Description3",
  "radioGroup",
  "radio,Label - Value 1,1",
  "radio,Label - Value 2,2",
  "radio,Label - Value 3,3",
],
[
  "question_3",
  "Title3",
  "Description3",
  "radioGroup",
  "radio,Yes,1",
  "radio,No,0"
]
```

The objective is to get only the objects that contain the id (to remove the **{"uiComponent": "Spacer"}** objects) and get only the **subFields** with these tags inside the array:

```
  "subFields": [
    {
      "type": "xxxx",
      "label": "xxxx",
      "value": xxxx
    },
```

I was able to flatten the JSON array by using the following JQ pattern:

[jq play 1](https://jqplay.org/s/KVSA7S_ES5)

```
.subFields[] | select(has("id") and .id != null)| {id: .id, type: .type, description: .description, anwers: .subFields}
```

and generated this result:

```
{
  "id": "question_1",
  "type": "radioGroup",
  "description": "Description1",
  "anwers": [
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "Yes",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "No",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "uiComponent": "SmallContent",
      "componentProps": {
        "text": "* If the answer to the above question is “Yes”, please contact the Support immediately."
      }
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id": "question_2",
  "type": "radioGroup",
  "description": "Description2",
  "anwers": [
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "Label - Value 1",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "Label - Value 2",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "Label - Value 3",
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "Other",
      "value": 13,
      "subFields": [
        {
          "id": "question_2a",
          "type": "string",
          "condition": {
            "type": "BinaryExpression",
            "operator": "==",
            "left": {
              "type": "Identifier",
              "name": "question_2"
            },
            "right": {
              "type": "Literal",
              "value": 13
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id": "question_2_b",
  "type": "radioGroup",
  "description": "Description3",
  "anwers": [
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "Label - Radio 1",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "Label - Radio 2",
      "value": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "Label - Radio 3",
      "value": 3
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id": "question_3",
  "type": "radioGroup",
  "description": "Description3",
  "anwers": [
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "Yes",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "label": "No",
      "value": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to remove these sections:

```
{
  "uiComponent": "SmallContent",
  "componentProps": {
    "text": "* If the answer to the above question is “Yes”, please contact the Support immediately."
  }
}
```

and

```
  "subFields": [
    {
      "id": "question_2a",
      "type": "string",
      "condition": {
        "type": "BinaryExpression",
        "operator": "==",
        "left": {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "name": "question_2"
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "Literal",
          "value": 13
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

I played a little bit arround with this jq for the question_3 only:

[jq play 2](https://jqplay.org/s/a-UWCazubc)

```
.subFields[] |  {id: .id, title: .title, description: .description, type: .type, subFields: .subFields} | select(has("id") and .id != null) | select(.id=="question_3") |  {id: .id, title: .title, description: .description, type: .type, questions: (.subFields[]|join(","))}
```

and produced this result:

```
{
  "id": "question_3",
  "title": "Title3",
  "description": "Description3",
  "type": "radioGroup",
  "questions": "radio,Yes,1"
}
{
  "id": "question_3",
  "title": "Title3",
  "description": "Description3",
  "type": "radioGroup",
  "questions": "radio,No,0"
}
```

and also

[jq play 3](https://jqplay.org/s/bJEKjPlTfE)

```
.subFields[] |  {id: .id, title: .title, description: .description, type: .type, subFields: .subFields} | select(has("id") and .id != null) | select(.id=="question_3") |  [.id, .title, .description, .type, (.subFields[]|join(","))]
```

resulting on this:

```
[
  "question_3",
  "Title3",
  "Description3",
  "radioGroup",
  "radio,Yes,1",
  "radio,No,0"
]
```

Can you help me improve those JQ pattern I created to get the intended results?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The following produces your first alternative:

```
.subFields[]
| select(.id?)
| { id, title, description, type} +
    (.subFields[] 
     | select(.type?) 
     | [.type,.label,.value] | join(",")
     |  { questions: .} )
```

Notice the two `select()` filters.

The key names are specified explicitly here to ensure the ordering you specified is honored.